# Merge a git branch with master a second time because the first changes were removed due to conflict

Tags: git, github, merge, bitbucket, git-branch

I have written some code on the branch **"template-change"** and merged this with **master** a long time ago (2 month).

Now, changes made on the master branch have been lost because of someone deleting the code from **master**.

I have tried to merge the branch again but git is giving me the error:

> "branch already merge with master"

I've also tried to **cherry-pick** commits one by one but that is also not working; **cherry-pick** picks empty commits.

For now, I created a new branch and made the changes on that branch again and pushed them to the master branch.

I want to know what is the best solution available for solving this type of issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout files from your old commit to a new name and then merge the changes accordingly. First you need to identify the files that are overwritten. Then identify the commit from which you want to get the file from.

By doing a `git log -1` in the **template-change** branch will give you the commit from which you want to get the files.

Now for each file that is overwritten, in the **master** branch, you need to checkout the file to a new name by:

```
git show <commit>:file_path > new_name
```

You can now merge the files by using any merge tool.